# Is it possible to create product keys for my electron application?

Tags: electron, serial-number, product-key

I want to build a desktop application and be able to publish product keys or serial numbers.Before the user can use the application he will be requested to enter the product key/serial number.

Similar to Microsoft Office when they provide keys like XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX

The idea I have is to sell the app based on licenses and providing product key for every device seems more professional than accounts (usernames and passwords).

so my questions are:

1) Is it possible to accomplish this with `electron`?

2) Can you advice me wether I should go for serial numbers (if it is doable) or accounts? or are there better options?

3) if you answered the second question. Please state why?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Edit for 2021: I'd like to revise this answer, as it has generated a lot of inquiries on the comparison I made between license keys and user accounts. I previously would almost always recommended utilizing user accounts for licensing Electron apps, but I've since changed my position to be a little more nuanced. For most Electron apps, license keys will do just fine.

Adding license key (synonymous with product key) validation to an Electron app can be pretty straight forward. First, you would want to somehow generate a license key for each user. This can be done using cryptography, or it can be done by generating a 'random' license key string and storing it in a database and then building a CRUD licensing server that can verify that a given license key is "valid."

For cryptographic license keys, you can take some information from the customer, e.g. their order number or an email address, and create a 'signature' of it using RSA cryptography. Using Node, that would look something like this:

```
const crypto = require('crypto')

// Generate a new keypair
const { privateKey, publicKey } = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
  // Using a larger key size, such as 2048, would be more secure
  // but will result in longer signatures.
  modulusLength: 512,
  privateKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' },
  publicKeyEncoding: { type: 'pkcs1', format: 'pem' },
})

// Some data we're going to use to generate a license key from
const data = 'user@store.example'

// Create a RSA signer
const signer = crypto.createSign('rsa-sha256')
signer.update(data)

// Encode the original data
const encoded = Buffer.from(data).toString('base64')

// Generate a signature for the data
const signature = signer.sign(privateKey, 'hex')

// Combine the encoded data and signature to create a license key
const licenseKey = `${encoded}.${signature}`

console.log({ privateKey, publicKey, licenseKey })
```

Then, to validate the license key within your Electron app, you would want to cryptographically 'verify' the key's authenticity by embedding the public (not the private!) key generated above into your application code base:

```
// Split the license key's data and the signature
const [encoded, signature] = licenseKey.split('.')
const data = Buffer.from(encoded, 'base64').toString()

// Create an RSA verifier
const verifier = crypto.createVerify('rsa-sha256')
verifier.update(data)

// Verify the signature for the data using the public key
const valid = verifier.verify(publicKey, signature, 'hex')

console.log({ valid, data })
```

Generating and verifying the authenticity of cryptographically signed license keys like this will work great for a lot of simple licensing needs. They're relatively simple, and they work great offline, but sometimes verifying that a license key is 'valid' isn't enough. Sometimes requirements dictate that license keys are not perpetual (i.e. 'valid' forever), or they call for more complicated licensing systems, such as one where only a limited number of devices (or seats) can use the app at one time. Or perhaps the license key needs a renewable expiration date. That's where a license server can come in.

A license server can help manage a license's activation, expirations, among other things, such as user accounts used to associate multiple licenses or feature-licenses with a single user or team. I don't recommend user accounts unless you have a specific need for them, e.g. you need additional user profile information, or you need to associate multiple licenses with a single user.

But in case you aren't particularly keen on writing and maintaining your own in-house licensing system, or you just don't want to deal with writing your own license key generator like the one above, I’m the founder of a software licensing API called [Keygen](https://keygen.sh) which can help you get up and running quickly without having to write and host your own license server. :)

Keygen is a typical HTTP JSON API service (i.e. there’s no software that you need to package with your app). It can be used in any programming language and with frameworks like Electron.

In its simplest form, validating a license key with Keygen is as easy as hitting a single JSON API endpoint (feel free to run this in a terminal):

```
curl -X POST https://api.keygen.sh/v1/accounts/demo/licenses/actions/validate-key \
  -d '{
        "meta": {
          "key": "C1B6DE-39A6E3-DE1529-8559A0-4AF593-V3"
        }
      }'
```

I recently put together an example of adding license key validation, as well as device activation and management, to an Electron app. You can check out that repo on GitHub: https://github.com/keygen-sh/example-electron-license-activation.

I hope that answers your question and gives you a few insights. Happy to answer any other questions you have, as I've implemented licensing a few times now for Electron apps. :)

Comment: +1, How could I maintain license offline if a user doesn't use internet post initial one-time license validation through the Keygen API?

Comment: @ajay you could store it or a representation of it in some type of local storage when the user first inputs the license key, and then only prompt for a license key if a key doesn't exist in local storage. If they key eventually expires, then it'd be a good idea to store the expiry in local storage as well or revalidate the key (e.g. at each launch) when the user has internet access.

Comment: Thanks, @ezekg. Could you also guide how to prevent changes in the license validation/logic javascript code in the deployed packages?

Comment: You would need to obfuscate your code. In reality, there's really no way to completely stop somebody from cracking your software, regardless of the language it's written in. I would use something like uglifyjs to obfuscate JS and then require a valid license key for downloads (e.g. updates) and support and that'll get you 90% of the way there. In the end, it really depends on your business requirements as to what measures you are willing to take to prevent crackers. Feel free to reach out to me at support@keygen.sh and we can discuss in more detail.

Comment: I am looking for a solution in which a user can't redistribute code even after downloading by a valid license key or any other means.Obfuscating would surely restrict it up to a level. Fine, I will discuss it further on the support id. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Just for future readers, in that case, you would likely want to implement machine tracking via fingerprinting, which can be done through the API. It will essentially lock a license to a specific machine (or machines, plural). Anyways, look forward to the continued discussion over email.

Comment: Code could be also protected by ASAR check both links https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/application-packaging/   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dz5SnmBzBXc

Comment: One can "crack" such licensing in about 5 minutes:
- local server serving a required response

Comment: @scibuff you can verify request signatures and use validation nonces to combat low effort cracks like that.

Answer (score 4):

1. YES but concerning the software registration mechanism, IT IS HARD and it needs a lot of testing too.
2. If 90% of your users have internet access you should definitely go with the user accounts or some OAUTH 2.0 Plug and play thing (login with facebook/gmail/whatever)
3. I built a software licensing architecture from scratch using crypto and the fs module , and it was quite a journey (year) !

Making a good registration mechanism for your software from scratch is not recommended  , electron makes it harder because the source code is relatively exposed.

That being said , if you really wanna go that way  , bcrypt is good at this (hashs), you need a unique user identifier to hash , you also need some kind of persistence (preferably a file ) where you can store the user license , and you need to  hide the salt that you are using for hashing  either by hashing the hash... or storing small bits of it in separate files.

this will make a good starting point for licensing but it's far from being fully secured.

Hope it helps !

Comment: thank you for answering. I have couple of questions after reading your answer. 1) what is dragons? 2) I want to implement the app for an institution where I will be giving the users the usernames and passwords, therefore social network logins isn't what I am looking for. After that being said, is it still preferable to provide user accounts if they have internet access?

Comment: I am sorry for my late respond (Moving houses) 0_o

Comment: Yes ,  forget about software licensing and go for accounts login with the help of a library it will save you some time .

Comment: okay thanks for your answer, will probably use the accounts as you said

Answer (score 2):

There are many services out there which help you add license key based software licensing to your app. And to ensure your customers don't reuse the key, you would need a strong device fingerprinting algorithm.

You can try out [Cryptlex](https://cryptlex.com). It offers a very robust licensing solution with advanced device fingerprinting algo. You can check out the [Node.js](https://docs.cryptlex.com/node-locked-licenses/using-lexactivator/using-lexactivator-with-node.js) example on [Github](https://github.com/cryptlex/lexactivator-nodejs) to add licensing to your electron app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it *is* possible.

I myself desired this feature, and I found related solutions such as [paid video tutorials](https://beyondco.de/course/desktop-apps-with-electron/licensing-your-apps/offline-license-key-validation), online solutions [with [Keygen](https://github.com/keygen-sh/example-electron-license-activation)], and other random hacks, but I wanted something that is **offline** and **free**, so I created my own repository for myself/others to use. Here's how it works.

### Overview

1. Install [`secure-electron-license-keys-cli`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-license-keys-cli). (ie. `npm i -g secure-electron-license-keys-cli`).
2. Create a license key by running `secure-electron-license-keys-cli`. This generates a `public.key`, `private.key` and `license.data`.
3. Keep `private.key` safe, but stick `public.key` and `license.data` in the root of your Electron app.
4. Install [`secure-electron-license-keys`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-license-keys). (ie. `npm i secure-electron-license-keys`).
5. In your **main.js** file, review this sample code and add the necessary binding.

```js
const {
    app,
    BrowserWindow,
    ipcMain,
} = require("electron");
const SecureElectronLicenseKeys = require("secure-electron-license-keys");
const path = require("path");
const fs = require("fs");
const crypto = require("crypto");

// Keep a global reference of the window object, if you don't, the window will
// be closed automatically when the JavaScript object is garbage collected.
let win;

async function createWindow() {

    // Create the browser window.
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: "App title",
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(
                __dirname,
                "preload.js"
            )
        },
    });

    // Setup bindings for offline license verification
    SecureElectronLicenseKeys.mainBindings(ipcMain, win, fs, crypto, {
        root: process.cwd(),
        version: app.getVersion(),
    });

    // Load app
    win.loadURL("index.html");

    // Emitted when the window is closed.
    win.on("closed", () => {
        // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
        // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
        // when you should delete the corresponding element.
        win = null;
    });
}

// This method will be called when Electron has finished
// initialization and is ready to create browser windows.
// Some APIs can only be used after this event occurs.
app.on("ready", createWindow);

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on("window-all-closed", () => {
    // On macOS it is common for applications and their menu bar
    // to stay active until the user quits explicitly with Cmd + Q
    if (process.platform !== "darwin") {
        app.quit();
    } else {
        SecureElectronLicenseKeys.clearMainBindings(ipcMain);
    }
});
```

6. In your **preload.js** file, review the sample code and add the supporting code.

```js
const {
    contextBridge,
    ipcRenderer
} = require("electron");
const SecureElectronLicenseKeys = require("secure-electron-license-keys");

// Expose protected methods that allow the renderer process to use
// the ipcRenderer without exposing the entire object
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
    licenseKeys: SecureElectronLicenseKeys.preloadBindings(ipcRenderer)
});
```

7. Review the sample **React** component how you can verify the validity of your license, and act accordingly within your app.

```js
import React from "react";
import {
  validateLicenseRequest,
  validateLicenseResponse,
} from "secure-electron-license-keys";

class Component extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.checkLicense = this.checkLicense.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.api.licenseKeys.clearRendererBindings();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Set up binding to listen when the license key is
    // validated by the main process
    const _ = this;

    window.api.licenseKeys.onReceive(validateLicenseResponse, function (data) {
      console.log("License response:");
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  // Fire event to check the validity of our license
  checkLicense(event) {
    window.api.licenseKeys.send(validateLicenseRequest);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.checkLicense}>Check license</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Component;
```

**You are done!**

### Further detail

To explain further, the license is validated by a request from the client (ie. front-end) page. The client sends an [IPC request](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer) to the main (ie. backend) process via this call (`window.api.licenseKeys.send(validateLicenseRequest)`).

Once this call is received by the backend process (which was hooked up because we set it up with this call (`SecureElectronLicenseKeys.mainBindings`)), the library code tries to decrypt `license.data` with `public.key`. Regardless if this succeeds or not, the success status is sent back to the client page (via IPC).

### How to limit license keys by version

What I've explained is quite limited because it doesn't limit the versions of an app you might give to a particular user. `secure-electron-license-keys-cli` includes flags you may pass when generating the license key to set particular major/minor/patch/expire values for a license.

If you wanted to allow major versions up to 7, you could run the command to generate a license file like so:
`secure-electron-license-keys-cli --major "7"`

If you wanted to allow major versions up to 7 and expire on 2022-12-31, you could run the command to generate a license file like so:
`secure-electron-license-keys-cli --major "7" --expire "2022-12-31"`

If you *do* run these commands, you will need to update your client page in order to compare against them, ie:

```js
window.api.licenseKeys.onReceive(validateLicenseResponse, function (data) {

    // If the license key/data is valid
    if (data.success) {

        if (data.appVersion.major <= data.major &&
            new Date() <= Date.parse(data.expire)) {

            // User is able to use app
        } else {
            // License has expired
        }
    } else {
        // License isn't valid
    }
});
```

The [repository page](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-license-keys-cli#options) has more details of options but this should give you the *gist* of what you'll have to do.

### Limitations

This isn't perfect, but will likely handle 90% of your users. This doesn't protect against:

- Someone decompiling your app and making their own license to use/removing license code entirely
- Someone copying a license and giving it to another person

There's also the concern how to run this library if you are packaging multiple or automated .exes, since these license files need to be included in the source. I'll leave that up to the creativity of you to figure out.

### Extra resources / disclaimers

I built all of the **secure-electron-*** repositories mentioned in this question, and I also maintain [`secure-electron-template`](https://github.com/reZach/secure-electron-template/) which has the setup for license keys already pre-baked into the solution if you need something turn-key.